# How to add verification inside any method in Keyword Driven Framework using selenium and java

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I am implementing Keyword Driven Framework and I have added a keyword inside my excel sheet and have written a method for it in selenium using java. 
Now the problem is when i am executing this script then at that time it is showing me as Pass/fail inside the excel but this Pass/fail is invalid since I am not verifying anything in this method, instead it is returning Pass if that method is executed i.e. when that element is found on the page else it is returning fail when it doesn't find that element.

For click keyword:
I want to add verification inside this method such as:
Pass -> when the button is enabled and it is clicked
Failed -> when the button is disabled and it is not clicked

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use selenium's [`isEnabled()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#isEnabled--) method for that e.g.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("elementID")).isEnabled();
```

you can use something like this

```
boolean enabled= driver.findElement(By.id("elementID")).isEnabled();
```

For this to work you would need to check the method which is writing pass/fail in the excel and you can use this logic in that function i.e. if enabled is true then it should write pass otherwise it should write fail.